# Why $K_7$ graph can't be embedded in Klein bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I already know, that $K_7$ induces a triangulation of a Torus and already constructed it. But what is the problem with Klein bottle? Is there a constructive proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a detailed proof including nice pictures in the book [Map colour theorem](https://books.google.at/books?id=EfoOCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=K7+cannot+be+embedded+into+Klein+bottle&source=bl&ots=oZ61nXDgeB&sig=DiDFo41gglBnWFH_BgB-WUn2DnA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjciLO2hfDLAhWFXRQKHeqkBxEQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=K7%20cannot%20be%20embedded%20into%20Klein%20bottle&f=false), see Theorem $4.11$ on page $69$. It is too long to reproduce it here.